# Is this the best way to wait for selenium WebElement?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(ExpectedConditions expectedConditions, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));

    IWebElement element =
        wait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
}
```

My questions:

How to put this `expectedConditions` instead of what is currently in my method ?

I try to change:

```
    IWebElement element =
        wait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
```

with this:

```
    IWebElement element =
        wait.Until<IWebElement>(expectedConditions(by));
```

And received this error:

> Method name expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Until method requires a predicate as first argument.
A predicate is a function that is called at a regular interval until it returns something different from `null` or `false`.

So in your case you need to make it return a predicate and not a `IWebElement`:

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> MyCondition(By locator) {
    return (driver) => {
        try {
            var ele = driver.FindElement(locator);
            return ele.Displayed ? ele : null;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException){
            return null;
        }
    };
}

// usage
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element1 = wait.Until(MyCondition(By.Id("...")));
```

Which is equal to :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("...")));
element.Click();
```

You could also use a lambda expression

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until((driver) => {
    try {
        var ele = driver.FindElement(By.Id("..."));
        return ele.Displayed ? ele : null;
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException){
        return null;
    }
});
element.Click();
```

Or an extension method:

```
public static IWebElement WaitElementVisible(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeout = 10) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).Until((drv) => {
        try {
            var ele = drv.FindElement(by);
            return ele.Displayed ? ele : null;
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException){ 
            return null;
        } catch (NotFoundException){ 
            return null; 
        }
    });
}


// usage
IWebElement element = driver.WaitElementVisible(By.Id("..."));
element.Click();
```

As you see, there is many ways to wait for an element is a specific state.